# Creating a playstore account for someone

Tags: google-play-store

I purchased an android for my stepdaughter who lives in another state. How can I set up a play store account for her so she can download apps? I have an IPhone myself

Comment: Its basically a Gmail account. Make one for her, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

To setup the Google play store account. You just need to setup a Google account within the Android device. This can be done when the phone is first turned on in the initial setup or can be done in settings within accounts.  [Google support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521798?hl=en&vid=1-635810726884534754-1090291105)